# How to send a file using netcat and then keep the connection alive?

Tags: sockets, unix, netcat

I am issuing the command:

```
netcat serveraddress myport < MY_FILE
```

The thing is, that netcat sends a message to close the connection once the file is sent.  I need to write messages from the console after sending that file. I remember to have done something to pipileline to stdin.. was it this?

```
netcat serveraddress myport < MY_FILE |
```

That isn't working now.

I'm on unix.

Extra info:  This did not assume control on server side (E.G. use netcat on serverside to listen for the inbound connection)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Perhaps you were doing:

```
cat MY_FILE - | ncat ...
```

(Note that I've intentionally mispelled netcat, because I believe `ncat` is a superior program.)

Comment: Thank you, that was it.  A big plus would be if you can add a little info about why that works, or some refference. (What's that "-"?)

Comment: The `-` tells cat to read stdin.  It first reads (and writes) `MY_FILE`, then reads stdin.  If stdin is a tty, then it simply blocks on input from the keyboard.

Answer (score 8):

Server side:

```
nc -k -l 10000 < my_in_file
```

Client side:

```
echo "bye" | netcat 192.168.1.6 10000 > my_in_file -
```

Comment: Thank you. However this did not work since server side is not using nc, what william proposed did.

Answer (score 6):

To keep listening for other connections use `-k` on `nc`.

suppose you want to make connection to server , server write to file and print to stdout ?

Server:

```
nc -k -l $PORT | tee file ( or > file without print to stdout)
```

Client

```
nc $IP $PORT < file_to_send
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the -q -1 option of nc:

```
echo MY_FILE | nc -q -1 192.168.0.1 9000
```

This way it will also work if the command is run in background.

Answer (score 1):

I realise this thread is very old but and the OP uses unix, for reference here is a windows equivalent to "cat FILE - | ncat HOST":

```
type FILE con | ncat HOST
```

Then type CTRL-Z or CTRL-C to end the connection.

**Notes**

- 'con' means console input, see http://ss64.com/nt/type.html
- It works with binary files.